# Refresh power bi client acces Token React

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I use power bi client to import visuals created by power bi into a web application
the integration of the visuals is perfect and I can consult all my dashboards
but my problem is that these dashbords stay only one hour and if we want to see them again on the web application we had to change an accestoken provided on power bi service
is there a way to bring back this new token every time
someone can help me find a solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to refresh your access token once it is expired:

1. Refresh token directly, you can use `setAccessToken` API to refresh your access token without reloading the report.

example:

```
await report.setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
```

2. If you are using Azure AD token for embed for your organization, you can use the automatic approach.
   You'll have to set an event hook in the embedding configuration parameters. Before the current token expires, the event hook will call a method that generates a new access token and assigns it to the embedded object.

example:

```
let getNewAccessToken = async function () {
        // Code you need to add for generating new Azure AD token
        return token;
    };

let config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        accessToken: “eyJ0 …”,
        embedUrl: “https: …”,
        id: “123 …”,
        eventHooks: {
            accessTokenProvider: getNewAccessToken
        }
    };
```

**Reference:**

[Refresh the access token in Power BI embedded analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/refresh-token)